# Passing array of dates to Javascript sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm having problem with javascript sort function. I have this function:

```
var compare = function(a, b) {
    if(a.last_nom < b.last_nom) {
      return -1;
    }

    if(a.last_nom > b.last_nom) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

And the I call it with:

```
var sortedData = fullData.sort(compare);
```

But I don't know how to pass dates correctly.

You can find jsbin example [here](https://jsbin.com/weniga/edit?html,output)

Thank you in advance

As requested, to make sense of my code here is full code:

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" href="http://www.mzirafos.lt/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mzirafos.lt/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Mėmelio Žirafos - Facebook feeds page</title>

  <style>
    html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    header {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .progress {
      top: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .event-only .not-event {
      display: none;
    }
    .post-by {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .post-date {
      display: block;
    }
    .card .card-content .card-title {
      line-height: 26px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    img.responsive-img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="hide" id="content">
    <!--header-->
    <header>
      <nav class="top-nav">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <p>Mėmelio Žirafos Facebook feeds page</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!--end header-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!--checkbox to show all posts or events only-->
        <div class="col s6">
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="events-only" />
            <label for="events-only">Show events only</label>
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--end checkbox-->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <h3 class="center-align" id="posts-acc-title">Facebook posts</h3>
        <!--posts wrapper-->
        <div class="col s12" id="fb-posts-wrap"></div>
        <!--end posts wrapper-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sugar/1.4.1/sugar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {

      /*
       * Our Globals
       */

      var html = '';

      var finalData = [];

      var token = 'CAAQYWWjo5zkBAGlqs2AxxsWKcgWEI0VM3UA7555dhCQEOCTu9VW91tpfaNvrt4tS0w8DkxPJHvRENRrMeDT9QC1aSvHdZA7nhw9ZBqZAyUhMM6PTQoJggn7pJRHEO8xQJp8lsGZAqixVU8SvrMlhUUhwmzB11h9ISqd3MvmoD4aVZBPPD1geO';

      var baseURL =
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{slug}/feed?fields=picture,created_time,message,link,type,description,caption,full_picture,id,admin_creator,from&limit=50&access_token={token}';

      var slugs = [{
        slug: 'sisaidgallery',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'duzenos',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'bbcnews',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'Klaipeda.renginiai',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'PORTbyBarBara',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'Kastonas',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: 'klaipedosdramosteatras',
        complete: false
      }, {
        slug: '238899589464193',
        complete: false
      }];

      /*
       * allComplete
       */
      var allComplete = function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < slugs.length; i++) {
          if (slugs[i].complete === false) {
            return false;
          }
        }

        return true;
      };

      /*
       * makeURL
       */
      var makeURL = function(url, token, slug) {
        return url.replace('{token}', token).replace('{slug}', slug);
      };

      /*
       * Date formatter
       */
      var dateFormatter = function(date) {
        var dateFormat = '{HH}:{mm}, {Weekday}, {d} {Month}, {yyyy}';
        return Date.create(date).format(dateFormat);
      }

      /*
       * Mark slug as complete
       */
      var completeSlug = function(mySlug) {
        for (var i in slugs) {
          if (slugs[i].slug === mySlug) {
            slugs[i].complete = true;
          }
        }
      };

      var copyTextID = 100;

      /*
       * template
       */
      var template = '' +
        '<div class="card blue-grey darken-1 hoverable {isEvent}">' +
        '<div class="card-content white-text">' +
        '<span class="post-date">Posted on: {fb-post-date}</span>' +
        '<span class="post-by">Post by: {fb-post-from}</span>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col s2">' +
        '<img class="responsive-img" src="{fb-image}" alt=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col s10" id="post-target-{fb-post-id}">' +
        '<span class="card-title">{fb-post-title}</span>' +
        '<p>{fb-post-text}</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="card-action">' +
        '<a target="_blank" href="{fb-post-link}">Open post</a>' +
        '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn white-text red darken-1 hoverable" data-clipboard-target="#post-target-{fb-post-id}"><i class="material-icons right">subject</i>Copy</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';


      /*
       * checking title, text and images
       */

      var replaceUndefined = function(str) {
        return str === undefined ? '' : str;
      };

      var replaceImage = function(str) {
        return str === undefined ? 'https://placehold.it/350x150' : str;
      };

      /*
       * bindTemplate
       */
      var bindTemplate = function(template, obj) {

        return template
          .replace('{isEvent}', obj.type === 'event' ? '' : 'not-event')
          .replace('{fb-image}', replaceImage(obj.picture))
          .replace('{fb-post-from}', obj.from.name)
          .replace('{fb-post-title}', replaceUndefined(obj.description))
          .replace('{fb-post-text}', replaceUndefined(obj.message))
          .replace('{fb-post-link}', obj.link)
          .replace('{fb-post-date}', dateFormatter(obj.created_time))
          .replace(/{fb-post-id}/g, obj.id);

      };

      var makeAjax = function(fbUrl, next, slug) {
        $.ajax({
          url: fbUrl
        }).done(function(data) {
          next(data, slug);
        });
      };

      /*
       * renderTemplate
       */
      var renderTemplate = function() {
        $('#fb-posts-wrap').html(html);
      };

      /*
       * makeAjaxCalls
       */
      var makeAjaxCalls = function(slugs) {

        slugs.forEach(function(slug) {
          makeAjax(makeURL(baseURL, token, slug.slug), showAllPosts, slug.slug);
        });

      };

      /*
       * Flatten data
       */
      var flattenData = function(data) {
        var fullData = [];
        var empty = [];

        data.forEach(function(row) {
          fullData.push(row.data);
        });

        return empty.concat.apply(empty, fullData);
      };

      var compare = function(a, b) {
        if (a.last_nom < b.last_nom) {
          return -1;
        }

        if (a.last_nom > b.last_nom) {
          return 1;
        }

        return 0;
      }

      var showAllPosts = function(data, slug) {

        // Let's first mark this slug as complete
        completeSlug(slug);

        // And store our data
        finalData.push(data);

        if (allComplete()) {

          // merge all data
          var fullData = flattenData(finalData);

          // sort all data and
          var sortedData = fullData.sort(compare);

          // build the html
          sortedData.forEach(function(obj) {
            html += bindTemplate(template, obj);
          });

          // call the renderTemplateFunction
          renderTemplate();

          // finally hide the progress bar
          $('.progress').fadeOut();
          $('#content').removeClass('hide');
        }

      };


      /*
       * Listen to the change in the checkbox
       */
      $('#events-only').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          // hide the non events with css
          $('#fb-posts-wrap').addClass('event-only');
        } else {
          // show the non events with css
          $('#fb-posts-wrap').removeClass('event-only');
        }
      });

      /*
       * Kick off
       */
      makeAjaxCalls(slugs);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question. In this case, you've omitted important code (for instance, what's `fullData`?).

Comment: One of the key words above was [***minimum***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

What is `last_nom`? There is no such function in [JS Date specification](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Try this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.getTime() > b.getTime())
        return 1;
    if (a.getTime() < b.getTime())
        return -1;
    return 0
}
var sortedDatesArray = unsortedDatesArray.sort(compare);
```

Comment: there's no function getTime

Comment: I get 'Uncaught TypeError: a.getTime is not a function'

Comment: So probably your array is not a Dates array. Check your objects with debugger (inspect the variable). I guess you use some objects which have date, so find the method returning `Date` object from your items and use its getTime()` function.